# Railway metric, help showing that the space is bounded but not compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I am studying metric spaces and I came across this exercice that I was able to solve only partially. Any help and hints will be appreciated.

Let $X= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \mid \mid x \mid \mid \leq 1 \}$ on which we consider the railway metric defined by

$ d(x,y)= \mid \mid x-y \mid \mid$ if $x$ and $y$ are on the same line through the origin and

$d(x,y)= \mid \mid x \mid \mid + \mid \mid y \mid \mid$ otherwise.

I could show that this is indeed a metric, I could show that the space is complete but now I have to show that $(X,d)$ is bounded but not compact. Also, is this space separable ? Since $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, I would say yes, but I am not sure.

Any hints or ideas on how to show that this space is bounded and not compact ?

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

The distance between any two points is never greater than $2$. And the sequence$$\left(\cos\left(\frac1n\right),\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$$has no convergent subsequence. This follows from the fact that the distance between any two points of the sequence is equal to $2$. So, no subsequence is a Cauchy sequence. In particular, no subsequence converges.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The boundless condition seems really simple now. For the compactness, I don't quite see why this is the case, sorry. I was trying to find a cover with no finite sub cover, using the fact that the boundary of any ball not centered at the origin contains infinitely many elements. Could you please explain me why the sequence has no convergent subsequence ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thank you very much. Do you agree with my argument on why this space is separable ?

Comment: No. The space $X$ is *not* homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Okay, I am a bit confused, I thought that the open $n$-Ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin $\mathbb{B}^n$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ via the transformation $F: \mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $F(x)=\frac{x}{1-\mid x \mid}$. The inverse would then be given by $F^{-1}(y)= \frac{y}{1+ \mid y \mid}$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: The open unit ball is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ if we consider in it the usual metric. But here the matric is the railway metric.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0$ be the origin in $\Bbb R^2.$ For each line $L$  in $\Bbb R^2$ thru $0,$ the set $L'= (L\cap X)$ \ $\{0\}$ is open in $(X,d)$ and is non-empty.

And if $L_1\ne L_2$ then $L_1'$ and $L'_2$ are disjoint, because  two unequal lines  thru $0$ in $\Bbb R^2$ meet $only$  at $0.$ A dense subset in $(X,d)$ would have at least one point in each $L',$ and the set of all $L'$ is uncountable.

So $(X,d)$ is not  separable .

A compact metric space $(S,d)$ is separable. One way to prove this is:  For  each $n\in \Bbb N$ the set of all open balls of radius $1/n$ is an open cover of $S,$ so let $S_n$ be a finite subset of $S$ such that $F_n=\{B_d(x,1/n):x\in S_n\}$ covers $S.$ Then $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}S_n $is  countable and dense.